# Как отключить подсветку синтаксиса

Tags: html5, pycharm

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Все настройки перерыл в pycharm, не нашёл как это выключить, раздражает очень
Если что, подсветка синяя которая

Answer (score 0):

Нашел. Кому надо: Settings > General > Appearance > Enable HTML/XML tag tree highlighting